# Ubuntu uninstalled, cannot access Windows partition.

Tags: grub2, dual-boot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on)

I gave my dad my old laptop which had Windows dual booted with Ubuntu 12.04, he did a Windows recovery and chose the option 'entire HD'. Now when he tries to boot it give this error:

`error no such partition grub rescue`

I am guessing it's because it was going to the Ubuntu bootloader, how do I fix this so he can access Windows again?

Comment: See this answer: http://askubuntu.com/a/143482/27968